# grid view paging not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Grid View paging not work means it not display record page by page

```
<data:EntityGridView ID="GridOpen" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false"
                                                        DefaultSortDirection="Ascending" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="GridOpen_PageIndexChanging"
                                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridOpen_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="OrderNo" Width="100%"
                                                        OnRowDataBound="GridOpen_OnRowDataBound" ExcelExportFileName="Export_AccountTerms.xls">
                                                        <Columns>

  <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNo" HeaderText="Order No" SortExpression="[OrderNo]" />


</Columns>
```

This is my data source and Binding the grid

```
_actOpen = _actOrdServices.GetPaged("StatusID=1 AND AssignedDispatchBoardID = " + DispatchBoard + " AND CompanyId=" + Session["CompanyId"].ToString(), "OrderNo Desc", GridOpen.PageIndex, GridOpen.PageSize, out count);


 GridOpen.DataSource = _actOpen;
```

Also i have try for paging

```
GridOpen.AllowPaging = true;
```

my Store procedure is working fine but here i dont know this is not display paging in grid

Any guide will deeply welcome.

Comment: AllowPaging="false" make it "true."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your aspx code AllowPaging="false" make it "true."

Then in code behind PageIndexChanging event do this,

```
   protected void GridOpen_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridOpen.DataSource = _actOpen;
        GridOpen.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridOpen.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your allow paging property of the gridview is set to false
(AllowPaging="false")
make it true and check again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you have to done, it is also necessary to write the paging event in the aspx.cs:
1) Make sure you have done, allowed paging="true' in the aspx. page( in gridview).
2) Then register the event in the code:

```
protected void GridOpen_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridOpen.DataSource = YourOBJ.Method_yourmethod();
    GridOpen.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridOpen.DataBind();
}
```